# jQuery slide up/down: not effect content below it?

Tags: jquery, html, css, effects, slidedown

So I have a div that is displayed by default. I'm using a function to slideUp the element, then change the content, then slideDown back to reveal the new info.

And that's all working fine.

What's bothering me is that when the div is animating everything below it follows it up and down.

Basically, it seems like as it's hiding it's "display: none" -ing so to speak, meaning it's being taken out of the flow.
And I want it to be more like "visibility: hidden".

...if that makes sense (God, I hope it does. It has been a long week. =P)

Comment: It would make more sense if you post your code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements slide up to fill gaps when above elements are removed. For HTML, gravity is upward, which is why we build HTML downward(from the top of the browser, down).

Let's pretend your object sliding upward is as follows:

```
<div class="SlideUpDiv" style="height:500px; display:block;">Hello!</div>
```

What you need to do is wrap that div in another div that holds the same height:

```
<div class="slideUpContainer" style="height:500px; display:block;">
  <div class="slideUpDiv" style="height:500px; display:block;">Hello!</div></div>
</div>
```

This way, when the first element crushes, the gap will be held open by the parent div.

Comment: I thought about doing that. It seems like an easy way to do it. I just thought there might be some option with the jQuery effect that I was missing and I wanted to avoid adding a meaningless div. Is there no way to just pass jQuery something that says "even when this is gone, still hold it's place"?

Comment: I do not believe so. Your best bet is the HTML div. Having a div there will be lighter on the RAM anyway because in order for the jQuery function to be able to do that, it would have to make the spacer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest thing to do would be to put the Slide element inside a div with a fixed height. For example

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='slider'>
    <!-- content for slider here -->
    </div> <!-- close slider -->
</div>  <!--close wrapper -->
```

Then set then set set the slider jquery, I am assuming you have this done already and don't need to see it.

The CSS would look like:

```
div.wrapper {height: 250px; overflow: hidden;}
div.slider {max-height: 250px;}
```

This way, the slider moves up and down inside a fixed size element and the rest of the elements will be unaffected.